# How to remove element from array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I've got such kind of structure. here is an example

```
{
    "_id" : "423dswar23ew2355",
    "competitions" : [ 
        "24",
        "58", 
        "354",
        "361"
    ],
}
```

How I can delete for example "58" item from "competitions" array.

I've seen some kind of solution like

```
{ $pull: { competitions: { $eq: "58" }}}
```

But my mongo says thar

> MongoError: unknown top level operator: $eq

So can anybody come up with some more simple but at the same time working solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
db.col.update({_id: "423dswar23ew2355"}, { $pull: { "competitions": "58" } })
```

Remember that since you have strings you should pass "58" as a string.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the new versions:

```
db.col.updateOne({_id: "423dswar23ew2355"}, { $pull: { "competitions": "58" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the 58, you can use

`db.lists.update({}, {$unset : {"competitions.2" : 1 }})`

then

`db.lists.update({}, {$pull : {"competitions" : null}})`

hope it could help you